# How to use a function to create a text with "System.Windows.Forms"

Tags: windows, powershell, user-interface

```
# Initial config
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Variables
$ver="beta 1.0.1"
$inf=""
$debug=0

# Import objects
$MainWin = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$sound = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer

# MainWin
$MainWin.MaximizeBox = $false
$MainWin.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$MainWin.ClientSize = '500,200'
$MainWin.text = "Test " + $version
$MainWin.BackColor = "#222222"
$MainWin.FormBorderStyle = "FixedSingle"

# Functions
function Text ($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l,$m,$n,$o,$p,$q) {
    $p = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $p.Text = $a
    $p.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($b,$c)
    #$p.AutoSize = $true
    $p.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($d, $e, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::$f)
    $color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($g, $h, $i, $j)
    $p.ForeColor = $color
    $color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($k, $l, $m, $n)
    $p.BackColor = $color
    $p.Visible = $o
    $q.Controls.Add($p)
}

# function Butn ($a)

Text "Hola" 0 0 500 200 regular 255 255 255 255 255 100 200 100 $true label1 MainWin

# $p = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
# $p.Text = "Hola"
# $p.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(9,9)
# $p.AutoSize = $true
# $p.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(500, 200, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::regular)
# $color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)
# $p.ForeColor = $color
# $color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 155, 255, 111)
# $p.BackColor = $color
# $p.Visible = $true
# $MainWin.Controls.Add($p)

# Print Window
[void]$MainWin.ShowDialog()
```

I just started using powershell and this is the first working script I've done, so keep that in mind. I have been guided by online tutorials and I have been improvising some things, like the functions and creating the whole GUI from scratch.

The window is created correctly but the text is not displayed by the function, the code below when the function is called, which is all commented, is executed correctly.

I am trying to use a function to create a text, in the commented part below is an example that works, but the function does not, what am I doing wrong?

Output:

```
"You cannot call a method on an expression with a NULL value".
$q.Controls.Add($p)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Text "Hola" 0 0 500 200 regular 255 255 255 255 255 100 200 100 $true
> label1 MainWin

MainWin != $MainWin
MainWin - text
$MainWin - object

You pass arguments to a function, but you override variables in the function itself
Apparently you want to pass the $MainWin object to the function and use it there as $q

```
Text "Hola" 0 0 500 200 regular 255 255 255 255 255 100 200 100 $true label1 $MainWin
```

example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Variables
$ver="beta 1.0.1"
$inf=""
$debug=0

# Import objects
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$sound = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer


function get-MainWin($MaximizeBox,$StartPosition,$ClientSize,$text,$BackColor,$FormBorderStyle){
    $MainWin = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $MainWin.MaximizeBox = $MaximizeBox
    $MainWin.StartPosition = $StartPosition
    $MainWin.ClientSize = $ClientSize
    $MainWin.text = $text
    $MainWin.BackColor = $BackColor
    $MainWin.FormBorderStyle = $FormBorderStyle
    $MainWin
}

function Text ($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l,$m,$n,$o,$p,$q) {
    $p = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $p.Text = $a
    $p.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($b,$c)
    #$p.AutoSize = $true
    $p.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font($d, $e, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::$f)
    $color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($g, $h, $i, $j)
    $p.ForeColor = $color
    $color = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($k, $l, $m, $n)
    $p.BackColor = $color
    $p.Visible = $o
    $q.Controls.Add($p)
}

$text= "Test " + $version
$MainWin = get-MainWin $false "CenterScreen" '500,200' $text "#222222" "FixedSingle"
Text "Hola" 0 0 500 200 regular 255 255 255 255 255 100 200 100 $true label1 $MainWin
[void]$MainWin.ShowDialog()
```

this script works, but you won't see the text, as it merges with the background